# How can I get the value of a string that is not in the same class?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I get error messages in these two lines:

```
SignedData = verify.SignedDataverify;
Signature = verify.Signatureverify;
```

> Error CS1061: 'IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase' does not contain a definition for 'SignedDataverify' and no extension method 'SignedDataverify' accepting a first argument of type 'IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error CS1061: 'IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase' does not contain a definition for 'Signatureverify' and no extension method 'Signatureverify' accepting a first argument of type 'IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I get the value of the two string variables `SignedDataverify` and `Signatureverify`? I don't know how to get the values because they are not in the same class.

In this class, I want to get the values of `SignedDataverify` and `Signatureverify`:

**UPDATE: This code works.**

```
    string SignedData = "", Signature = "";

    public async Task<bool> PurchaseItem(string productId)
    {
        var purchaseSuccesful = false;

        if (CrossInAppBilling.IsSupported == true)
        {
            var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;
            try
            {
                var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync(ItemType.InAppPurchase);
                if (connected == true)
                {
                    var verify = DependencyService.Get<IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase>();
                    var purchase = await billing.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.InAppPurchase, "apppayload", verify);
                    SignedData = ((Verify)verify).SignedDataverify;
                    Signature = ((Verify)verify).Signatureverify;

                    ...
```

Verify.cs:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Plugin.InAppBilling.Abstractions;
using InapppurchaseTest;

namespace InapppurchaseTest
{
public class Verify : IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase
{
    const string key1 = @"XOR_key1";
    const string key2 = @"XOR_key2";
    const string key3 = @"XOR_key3";

    public string SignedDataverify = "", Signatureverify = "";

    public Task<bool> VerifyPurchase(string signedData, string signature, string productId = null, string transactionId = null)
    {
    #if __ANDROID__
        var key1Transform = Plugin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingImplementation.InAppBillingSecurity.TransformString(key1, 1);
        var key2Transform = Plugin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingImplementation.InAppBillingSecurity.TransformString(key2, 2);
        var key3Transform = Plugin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingImplementation.InAppBillingSecurity.TransformString(key3, 3);
        SignedDataverify = signedData;
        Signatureverify = signature
        return Task.FromResult(Plugin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingImplementation.InAppBillingSecurity.VerifyPurchase(key1Transform + key2Transform + key3Transform, signedData, signature));
    #else
        SignedDataverify = signedData;
        Signatureverify = signature;
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    #endif
    }
}
}
```

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/blob/master/docs/SecuringPurchases.md

Comment: If you have objects of these classes initialized in another class you can use them from there, right?

Comment: Looking at your code "SignedDataverify" & "Signatureverify" are members of the "Verify" class - try casting "verify" to that type.

Comment: Did you implement all the four components of your DependencyService? You need to define your interface. Then, implement it for each project (ios & android). After that, a very important step is to register your implement class with your dependency service. Finally, you can call it. Please take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: Is this what you wanting? `SignedData = (verify as Verify).SignedDataverify;`

Comment: @ roya zamiri At the moment, I only have an iOS project in my solution. Both classes(Verify.cs, Game1.cs is where I need to get SignedDataverify and Signatureverify) are in the same project. See my picture above. Is it necessary to add [assembly: Dependency (typeof (..))] somewhere?

Comment: You can have a try. Please add [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Verify))]  on your ios implementation.

Comment: It's not working. I added this line in Verify.cs but I get an error message: Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Verify' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: add "using InapppurchaseTest;" under other usings.

Comment: Thank you very much :) It works. I have tested it on my iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "DependencyService.Get()" method returns a reference to "IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase", then "verify" needs casting to the "Verify" class as "SignedDataverify" & "Signatureverify" are members of that class.

Try :

```
 SignedData = ((Verify)verify).SignedDataverify;
 Signature = ((Verify)verify).Signatureverify;
```

or

```
 SignedData = (verify as Verify)?.SignedDataverify;
 Signature = (verify as Verify)?.Signatureverify;
```

(The latter method will return null if the cast fails, the former will throw an exception - as your code is in a try-catch statement you may be happy to catch the exception or prefer null checking)

Comment: I tried the former method, but verify is always null. Then, I get this Exception.Message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". In addition, I set a breakpoint in the following line of code in the class Verify, but the breakpoint is never executed. SignedDataverify = signedData; Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Hobbit7: put a breakpoint after the call to _"DependencyService.Get<IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase>();"_ & check what type _"verify"_ is - the errors you get indicate that it is not a reference to an instance of the _"Verify"_ class.

Comment: I don't know how to find out of what type "verify" is. It just shows "null" when my cursor is on verify. I added an image above.

Comment: In addition, I have tried the latter method. In this case, SignedData, Signature and verify are null.

Comment: Then that indicates the call to _"DependencyService.Get<IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase>();"_ is returning null - so the is no instance of any class to get the data from. You need to find out why your are getting null returned - and you may need to add checking for null return as well.