# How can I add a DependencyService to my projects?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to add this DependencyService to my projects, but I don't know how to do it correctly.

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/blob/master/docs/SecuringPurchases.md

I have three projects in my solution, iOS project, Android project and SharedCode project.

1)I added the class Verify_Android to my Android project.

2)I added the class Verify_iOS to my iOS project.

3)I added the interface IVerify to my SharedCode project.

But I get some error messages and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
public Task<bool> VerifyPurchase()
```

> Error CS0106: The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item
>
> Error CS0531: 'IVerify.VerifyPurchase()': interface members cannot
>   have a definition

```
 public class Verify_Android : IVerify
```

> Error CS0535: 'Verify_Android' does not implement interface member
>   'IVerify.VerifyPurchase()'

```
public class Verify_iOS : IVerify
```

> Error CS0535: 'Verify_iOS' does not implement interface member 'IVerify.VerifyPurchase()'

In addition, I don't know how to call the interface from a class that is located in my SharedCode project. How can I call the interface?

IVerify:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Plugin.InAppBilling.Abstractions;

namespace SharedProject
{
public interface IVerify : IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase
{
    public Task<bool> VerifyPurchase()
    {
    }
}
}
```

Verify_Android:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AndroidProject.Android;
using SharedProject;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Verify_Android))]
namespace AndroidProject.Android
{
public class Verify_Android : IVerify
{
    public Verify_Android()
    {
    }

    const string key1 = @"XOR_key1";
    const string key2 = @"XOR_key2";
    const string key3 = @"XOR_key3";

    public string SignedDataverify = "", Signatureverify = "";

    public Task<bool> VerifyPurchase(string signedData, string signature, string productId = null, string transactionId = null)
    {
        var key1Transform = Plugin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingImplementation.InAppBillingSecurity.TransformString(key1, 1);
        var key2Transform = Plugin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingImplementation.InAppBillingSecurity.TransformString(key2, 2);
        var key3Transform = Plugin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingImplementation.InAppBillingSecurity.TransformString(key3, 3);
        SignedDataverify = signedData;
        Signatureverify = signature;
        return Task.FromResult(Plugin.InAppBilling.InAppBillingImplementation.InAppBillingSecurity.VerifyPurchase(key1Transform + key2Transform + key3Transform, signedData, signature));
    }
}
}
```

Verify_iOS:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using iOSProject.iOS;
using SharedProject;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Verify_iOS))]
namespace iOSProject.iOS
{
public class Verify_iOS : IVerify
{
    public Verify_iOS()
    {
    }

    const string key1 = @"XOR_key1";
    const string key2 = @"XOR_key2";
    const string key3 = @"XOR_key3";

    public string SignedDataverify = "", Signatureverify = "";

    public Task<bool> VerifyPurchase(string signedData, string signature, string productId = null, string transactionId = null)
    {
        SignedDataverify = signedData;
        Signatureverify = signature;
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: have you read the "Setup" docs?

Comment: I have read this https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/ but I don't know how to implement DependencyService.Get<IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase>(); correctly in my projects.

Comment: you don't - you install the NuGet package, which is the FIRST thing listed under Setup

Comment: I have installed the NuGet package. What Setup docs do you mean?

Comment: the doc you linked to - click "Getting Started" and the first thing it says is "Setup".  You do not need to explicitly deal with the DependencyService, the nuget package should handle that for you.

Comment: But "var verify = DependencyService.Get<IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase>();" always returns null when I use it, even if I don't create a class named Verify in my projects. https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/SecuringPurchases.html

Comment: sorry, I see what you're doing now.  Do you have an implementation of that interface in the relevant platform project?  Is it registered properly?

Comment: I have a class named Verify.cs in my SharedCode project. Is it necessary to have the same class in my Android and iOS projects? I don't know how to register it properly.

Comment: Yes.  The very first line of the doc you link to says "Each platform handles security of In-App Purchases a bit different."  That means you have to implement it in your platform project and use DependencyService to access that code from the shared project.  Read the DependencyService docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: I added an interface but it's not working.

Comment: neither of your platform classes are implementing the Interface you created

Comment: can you also add a description of the error @Hobbit7

Comment: I added my new code but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

> In addition, I don't know how to call the interface from a class that
>   is located in my SharedCode project. How can I call the interface?

You can use:

```
DependencyService.Get<IVerify>().VerifyPurchase(signedData, signature);
```

Also, you can update your interface declaration with:

```
public interface IVerify : IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase
{
    Task<bool> VerifyPurchase();
}
```

and then path your instance during purchasing:

```
var purchase = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.InAppPurchase, "apppayload", DependencyService.Get<IVerify>().VerifyPurchase(signedData, signature));
```

Comment: I tried it like this but it's not working.  var verify = DependencyService.Get<IVerify>().VerifyPurchase(signedData, signature); var purchase = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.InAppPurchase, "apppayload", verify); In addition I still get an error message here: public class Verify_iOS : IVerify Error CS0535: 'Verify_iOS' does not implement interface member 'IVerify.VerifyPurchase()'

Comment: In this link you can see how it works without interface, but with an interface I don't know how to do it correctly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56772570/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-string-that-is-not-in-the-same-class